# Issues with dependencies when installing Geary

Tags: apt, dependencies, geary

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and I'm trying to install Geary after adding the Yorba ppa. I'm getting the following returned every time with `sudo apt-get install geary` :

```
[sudo] password for tim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 geary : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (< 2.1.0) but 2.2.1-2ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa0 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone help with this? I've tried many, many different things based on what I've read in different forums and nothing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: tim@tim-Aspire-V5-571G:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tim@tim-Aspire-V5-571G:~$

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to install, what is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0` is currently 1.10.2-0ubuntu3 on Ubuntu 13.10.

First, check your current version :

```
dpkg -l | grep libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

If it is UNDER (<) 2.1.0, just prevent it from upgrading :

```
sudo apt-mark hold libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

If it is SUPERIOR TO (>) 2.1.0, you'll have to install an older version, but that'll risk to break your Gnome installation. Your best shot would be to find a PPA for Geary that has been build for > 2.1.0